# Insert Shell Command Output in Sed and replace existing file line

Tags: shell, scripting, cpanel, vps

I am trying to create a shell script, which needs to run on boot of new VPS Created. New VPS will be created with cPanel/WHM Panel pre-installed on CentOS 7 64bit template. Shell script needs to change the IP address of the VPS, with new IP address assigned to VPS while creation and reboot the cpanel service.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\e[1;36;40m Modifying parameters in cpanel shared IP configuration \e[0m"
ipchange="$(ip addr show | grep 'venet0:0' | awk '{ print $2}')"
echo "$ipchange"
sed -i -e 's/"ADDR 127.0.0.1$"/"ADDR $ipchange"/g' /etc/wwwacct.conf
echo -e "\e[1;36;40m Restarting cPanel \e[0m"
systemctl restart cpanel.service  > /dev/null 2>&1
echo -e "\e[1;36;40m Restart cpanel completed \e[0m"
```

I need to know how can I insert a partial output of below command

```
ip addr show | grep 'venet0:1' | awk '{ print $2}'
```

Example OUTPUT

```
bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/32
```

Only need to copy `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` and insert in `/etc/wwwacct.conf` file by removing existing

```
ADDR 127.0.0.1
```

With new IP

```
ADDR bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
```

Save the existing file and restart the cpanel services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your ip change you can use cut :

```
ip addr show | grep 'venet0:1' | awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1
```

And your sed should use double quotes to make the shell expand the $ipchange variable :

```
sed -i -e "s/ADDR 127.0.0.1/ADDR $ipchange/g" /etc/wwwacct.conf
```

Comment: @GAD3R my answer was based on the OP mentioning the example output `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/32`. I cannot know what he actually obtains with `ip addr show | grep 'venet0:1' | awk '{ print $2}'` on his machine